# fin in BSON documents with MongoDB C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I have the following document in my MongoDB test database:

```
    db.a.find()
   {[ {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5113d680732fb764c44qweq"),
        "Builds" : [
                {
                    "level" : 1,
                    "rank" : 2
                },
                {
                    "level" : 3,
                    "rank" : 4
                }
              ]
}, {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5113d680732fb764c4464fdf"),
        "Builds" : [
                {
                    "level" : 3,
                    "rank" : 5
                },
                {
                    "level" : 3,
                    "rank" : 4
                }
              ]
    }
]}
```

I need find level which => 1 and <= 2
May you help me?
It is possible do with mongocxx?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find in BSON documents with MongoDB C++ driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998609/find-in-bson-documents-with-mongodb-c-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find(
  document{} << "Builds.level" << open_document <<
    "$gte" << 1 <<
    "$lte" << 2
  << close_document << finalize);

for(auto doc : cursor) {
  std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
}
```

The mongo raw query which would fetch is the following :

```
db.a.find({"Builds.level":{$gte:1}, "Builds.level":{$lte:2}})
```

Comment: Can you say how can I put few conditions ?
Like this and second "Builds.rank" >=3;

Comment: You mean you want multiple if else block kind of thing. if i understand correct.

Comment: its like if("Builds.level" >= 1 && "Builds.level"  <=2 &&  "Builds.rank" >=4) ....

Comment: Multiple, where I may put few condotions

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998609/find-in-bson-documents-with-mongodb-c-driver
new topic

Comment: we can use $or to acheive this. will try to work out in a while and post answer in the new question you asked

Answer (score 1):

Think of you are finding data that greater then 1 and less then from 2 then you are go with mongodb then it's look like following:

```
db.getCollection('a').find({$and: [{'Builds.level': {$gte: 1}},{'Builds.level': {$lte: 2}}]})
```